# Bash background execution not returning

Tags: bash, shell-script, parallelism

I am trying to write a script that has the purpose to parallelize an execution (a program that creates some files) running the processes in background and, when all commands in the for loop are done, will perform an extra command (namely move all produced files in another folder). This is what I came out with for the moment:

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in ./lqns/*.lqn
do
    java -jar DiffLQN.jar $f &
done
mv ./lqns/*.csv csvs
```

The parallelism works, but they never reach the `mv` line and the terminal waits and doesn't return. Why is it not returning? How do I fix this?

Maybe the problem is the `&` of the final for instance? Because it waits for another command but there's nothing more? Even if adding the `mv` line I thought would have solved it...

Comment: Does it not run, or does it run immediately, before the (presumably) output csv files are generated?

Comment: The csvs files are created correctly in the `lqns` folder. I wish the execution to reach the `mv` line and then return but it simply stays on hold without moving the files in the `csvs` folder.

Comment: Yes, but are the csv files created by the `java` command? The thing is that your `mv` will run almost immediately: since all your processes are sent to the background, the loop will exit in milliseconds and the `mv` will be run immediately.  So if the csv files are generated by the java commands, the `mv` won't find anything to copy. Is that what is happening?

Comment: Oh you are right! I didn't think about that. Yes, the `java` command generates the `csv` files but the `mv` command doesn't do anything... So that is definitely the explanation. How do I ensure that the `mv` command is run only after all `java` commands finished the execution?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the csv files are generated by the java command, this will fail because the `mv` will run before any files have been generated. Since all java processes are sent to the background, the loop will finish almost immediately, so the script continues to the `mv` which finds no files to move and so does nothing.

A simple solution is to use `wait`. From `help wait` (in a bash shell):

```
$ help wait 
wait: wait [-fn] [-p var] [id ...]
    Wait for job completion and return exit status.
    
    Waits for each process identified by an ID, which may be a process ID or a
    job specification, and reports its termination status.  If ID is not
    given, waits for all currently active child processes, and the return
    status is zero.  If ID is a job specification, waits for all processes
    in that job's pipeline.
```

The relevant bit here is "If ID is not given, waits for all currently active child processes". This means that you can just add `wait` after your loop and that will make the script wait until all child processes are finished before continuing:

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in ./lqns/*.lqn
do
    java -jar DiffLQN.jar "$f" &
done

wait

mv ./lqns/*.csv csvs
```

Alternatively, you can combine the `java` and `mv` commands:

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in ./lqns/*.lqn
do
    java -jar DiffLQN.jar "$f" && mv /lqns/*.csv csvs &
done
```

Another, possibly better, option is to use GNU `parallel` (which should be in the repositories of whatever operating system you are running), a tool designed for precisely this sort of thing. With it, you could do:

```
parallel java -jar DiffLQN.jar ::: ./lqns/*.lqn
mv ./lqns/*.csv csvs
```

Comment: Adding `wait` worked perfectly! Thank you very much. Just a curiosity: why do you think the implementation with `parallel` could be better?

Comment: @Robb1 because it is an incredibly powerful and versatile tool. You can tell it to only run N processes at a time, and even pass it a file with the number of processes to run in parallel and changing the number in the file lets you change the number running without stopping and restarting. It has great tools for collecting the files you want as input (note how your whole script became just two commands), it can spread load across multiple computers on the same network, it's just a much better and more powerful tool.